# Using recursion to finds number of combinations of selecting 5 cards from 52 cards, 3819816 combinations found instead of 2598960

Tags: javascript, recursion

I was trying to use recursion to list all combinations of selecting 5 cards from 52 cards:

```js
const cards=[];
for(let i=0;i<52;i++){
  cards.push(i);
}
const s=new Set();
const recursion=function(arr,n){
  if(arr.length<5){
    for(let i=n;i<cards.length;i++){
      recursion(arr.concat([cards[i]]),i);
    }
  }else{
    s.add(arr.join(","));
  }
};
recursion([],0);
document.write(s.size);
```

The expected count should be 2598960, but the output now is 3819816, whats wrong with the code?

Comment: If you look at the results, you'll see you're including where you're drawing the same card, eg card[0], card[0]], card[0]], card[0]], card[0] - a card can only be drawn once.   Try with a smaller set, eg just 5 cards and actually look at the results.  How many combinations of drawing 5 cards from 5 cards are there?  Depends on if you count "in any order" or not - logically, there's only 1, but your algorithm gives 126.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reducing the number of cards to 5, and examining the results, you can see that the "current" card is included multiple times, ie:

```js
const cards = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  cards.push(i);
}
console.log(cards.length)
const s = new Set();
const recursion = function(arr, n) {
  if (arr.length < 5) {
    for (let i = n; i < cards.length; i++) {
      recursion(arr.concat([cards[i]]), i);
    }
  } else {
    s.add(arr.join(","));
    console.log(s.size, arr.join(","))
  }
};
recursion([], 0);
console.log(s.size);
```

```
 '0,0,0,0,0'
 '0,0,0,0,1'
 '0,0,0,0,2'
 etc
```

To remove the "current" card you can add 1 to the next recursion:

```
    recursion(arr.concat([cards[i]]), i+1);
```

giving, for 5 cards, the expected result: 1 combination

```js
const cards = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  cards.push(i);
}
console.log(cards.length)
const s = new Set();
const recursion = function(arr, n) {
  if (arr.length < 5) {
    for (let i = n; i < cards.length; i++) {
      recursion(arr.concat([cards[i]]), i+1);
    }
  } else {
    s.add(arr.join(","));
    console.log(s.size, arr.join(",")) 
  }
};
recursion([], 0);
console.log(s.size);
```

Then when applied to 52 cards, gives the expected result:

```js
const cards = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
  cards.push(i);
}
console.log(cards.length)
const s = new Set();
const recursion = function(arr, n) {
  if (arr.length < 5) {
    for (let i = n; i < cards.length; i++) {
      recursion(arr.concat([cards[i]]), i+1);
    }
  } else {
    s.add(arr.join(","));
    //console.log(s.size, arr.join(",")) 
  }
};
recursion([], 0);
console.log(s.size);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the code is producing an output of 3819816 instead of 2598960 is that the condition in the inner loop is not checking for the total length of the array, but only for the length of the current iteration.